# Autotest notifications on Ubuntu virtual environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, autotest, engineyard, vagrant

I am having trouble getting Rails autotest notifications to work on the Engine Yard Vagrant environment. On the Mac, I normally get the notifications via Growl. However, on the virtual environment (which runs Ubuntu) that doesn't work.

I tried running Linux notification setups such as libnotify+autotest-notification, but I get the following error:

```
libnotify-Message: Unable to get session bus: /bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.
** (notify-send:1004): CRITICAL **: dbus_g_proxy_connect_signal: assertion `DBUS_IS_G_PROXY (proxy)' failed
** (notify-send:1004): CRITICAL **: dbus_g_proxy_connect_signal: assertion `DBUS_IS_G_PROXY (proxy)' failed
** (notify-send:1004): CRITICAL **: dbus_g_proxy_call: assertion `DBUS_IS_G_PROXY (proxy)' failed
```

Another path would be to have Growl receive the notifications remotely, but I don't even know where to begin with that...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The web server won't have access to the desktop for notifications.  This is generally a good thing, for security reasons.

In the Growl installer `dmg` is a program `growlnotify`, which can be tweaked into building on most Posix-ish systems and can send remote notifications.  You will also have to configure Growl to receive remote notifications (System Prefeences > Other > Growl > Network).