# Sending autotest / guard desktop notifications from Vagrant Ubuntu VM to host (W7 and OS X)

Tags: tdd, vagrant, guard, autotest, growl

I have a question for all you Vagrants and TDD'ers out there,

**How can I make a Vagrant Ubuntu VM send autotest / guard notifications to a Windows 7 or OS X host?**

Details:

I'm trying to build my ultimate road-warrior development environment, so that I can jump between computers, OS's, and countries without worrying about reconfiguring my environment all the time. I'm using Vagrant to make disposable VMs that mirror our production environment, and letting me jump from my work computer (Windows 7) to my home computer (OS X) with minimal hassle.

I am trying to configure my Vagrant Ubuntu VM for use with Test-Driven Development (TDD), and make use of autotest / guard utilities to automatically run my tests on save, and display the results as desktop notifications on the host. I run the Vagrant VM in headless mode, so there is no desktop to receive the notifications, so I need them forwarded to the host.

I have a couple of leads, like using [Growl's remote notifications](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/help/default.aspx#network) (for receiving, but I don't know how to send them from the Ubuntu VM), or [hacking Growl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286120/autotest-notifications-on-ubuntu-virtual-environment), but I thought that this problem must have been addressed by others out there.

Comment: hmmm... looks like I might be able to use [ruby_gntp](http://snaka.info/ruby_gntp/) to send Growl's GNTP format to a port on the Vagrant VM, forward the port to the host OS, and use Growl or Growl for Windows to listen on that port. Maybe?

Comment: I thought I was the first to have this great idea. ;) Have you made it happen yet? Blog post somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to make it work on Windows 8 host and Ubuntu vagrant box:

Install gem `ruby_gntp` in rails.

Add to `Guardfile`:

```
`notification :gntp, :sticky => false, :host => '192.168.0.77', :port => '23053', :password => 'yourpassword'`
```

`192.168.0.77` is the IP of host machine, you can find it by running `ipconfig`.

`23053` - standard port for growl.

Install [growlforwindows](http://www.growlforwindows.com) and set network subscription to Vagrant box( [help](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/help/default.aspx#network))
with host `10.0.2.2`, port `23053` and password `yourpassword`

`10.0.2.2` - default IP of vagrant box gataway, you can confirm it by running `netstat -rn` in vagrant ssh.

Finally you can run `guard -p` and start tests.

If you get error *'refused'*, then it's wrong IP in Guardfile, for example this happens if I set gateway IP of windows machine instead of local IP.
If you get error *'Notiffany register filed'*, then it's wrong ip in growlforwindows.

Answer (score -1):

Well, why don't just forward all the tests' output to a file, then connect via SSH and see the results?
Basically `tail -f` command comes handy here.